# calculate the phone bills for user out of string

Tags: python, string

want to write a code that calculate bills for the phone user out of string.
the string format is as following:

```
"00:05:01,444-555-701,
00:06:03,111-222-333,
00:01:20,444-555-701"
```

first "hh:mm:ss,ddd-ddd-ddd"
hours:minutes:seconds, phone number

with the following conditions:

1- if the call duration is less than five minutes, every started second is for 5 cents.

2- if the call is more than or equal to five minutes, every started minute is for 150 cents.

3-the longest call for a phone number is for free, in the example 444-555-701 is for free since total calls duration is 00:06:23 is the longest call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]),([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3})")
searched = pattern.search("00:05:01,444-555-666")
if searched:
    print("Hours: " + str(searched.group(1)))
    print("Minutes: " + str(searched.group(2)))
    print("Seconds: " + str(searched.group(3)))
    print("Phone Number: " + str(searched.group(4)))
```

I'm not the best with regex however this will work, might be better options out there. But from this you'll be able to do everything you need